# Not able to Add Reference to other C# project in VIsual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

So I've created 2 projects in Visual Studio. Project A needs to use code from Project B. Project A has reference to a class in Project B and Visual Studio correctly highlights the error suggesting 'Add Reference to 'Project B' as a suitable fix.

When I select that a dialog comes up with title "Execute Suggested Action" and message 'Add reference to 'Project B'.' with a progress bar that is active like it's polling. However, it just hangs there on that dialog indefinitely without ever progressing beyond it. What could be causing that?

Comment: What are the project types of project A and B? Not each project type can reference all other types...

Comment: What version VS? Anything in the output window?

Comment: Ah, Project B is a plain C# application, generating the data to be displayed in Project A which is C# WPF GUI. Project B is using Target Framework .NET Core 3.1 whereas Project A is using .NET Framework 4.5.1. Could that be the issue? The lack of reported error is surprising if that is the case.

Comment: Repair the VS by using `setup.exe`. If this not work, try to add reference manually and report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=8).